# My Own Train vs. other 9v trains

Tags: trains, 9v

Does `My Own Train` series have any pros and cons (or pitfalls) against other 9v trains?

Seems that is a rich series but less popular comparing to, for example, Santa Fe or regular City sets. Why?

Comment: P.S. I want to propose `my-own-train` tag.

Comment: Not too sure what to answer, what kind of pros/cons are you looking for? I think the reasons for its lack of popularity may be quite subtle to pinpoint, too. Maybe it wasn't proposed by enough regular shops, or there was a lack of a complete set (since you had to buy a lot of things separately)... I don't know.

Comment: @Joubarc: Actually I just looking for any pitfalls, maybe that's really not bad items to buy, and looking overpriced Santa Fe are really overpriced.

Comment: If only those had come out early in my "HO train"-phase instead of the middle of my DarkAge....

Comment: @abatishchev On a possible [tag:my-own-train] tag: Thanks for the suggestion, but to be honest the current pro-tempore mods feel it's not eally useful at the moment, considering it probably wouldn't be used that much, and the [tag:trains] tag isn't really overcrowded right now.

Comment: @Joubarc: Got it. Sure, no problem. Maybe next year :)

Comment: @retracile: What does "HO train" stand for?

Comment: HO is a fairly common scale of model train, popular in the UK and (almost) identical with "OO" or "Double O" scale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "My Own Train" series only lasted from [2001 - 2004](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/MY_own_TRAIN), so it had a relatively short life span.  For the most part, they were very nice sets with rich details.

It most likely didn't resonate with collectors since the trains were available in various different colors, with or without a tender — this made it prohibitively expensive to *own* the collection since the price of the blue train was the same as the green train, and yet the only difference between sets were a few bricks that were switched from blue to green.  I, myself, bought a small and large train with tenders and the wagons, but I didn't bother with all of the other colors.

The *other* minus for the "My Own Train" series was that it didn't include any mini-figs, so it made it felt geared toward adults and yet, they weren't any more challenging in building than normal 9v trains.

Comment: I may say _minus_, because I prefer less minifigs but more train details :) so that really felt as geared toward adults